# Is there a bound on $\frac{1}{\lvert Q \rvert } \int_Q \lvert f(x) \rvert dx$ for periodic $L^1$ functions and hypercubes $Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

Let $\mathbb{T}^n := (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus and consider $L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$.

Then, any element $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$ can in fact be regarded as a locally integrable function on whole $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, let $Q$ be any bounded hypercube in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, is there some universal $C_n$ depending only on $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\lvert Q \rvert } \int_{Q} \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \leq C_n \lVert f \rVert_{L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)}
\end{equation}
holds for "all" $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T}^n)$?

I strongly suspect so, but cannot really prove anything from scratch. In fact, I think the same bound would be still valid even if we generalize $Q$ to all "compact measurable sets" in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bound would need to depend on the size of $Q$, and the constant may become very large if $|Q|\to 0$. Indeed, if $f$ has a singularity, then your desired inequality asserts that all averages of $f$ near the singularity are bounded by the $L^1$ norm of $f$, which clearly can’t occur since the average value of a function near a singularity is generally large. For an explicit example take $f(x) = 1/(2\sqrt{x})$ on $Q = [0,\epsilon]$ then $$\frac1{|Q|}\int_Q |f| = \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\epsilon} = |Q|^{-1/2}$$ which blows up as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Morally speaking, the left hand side should approximate the local behavior of $f$ as $|Q|\to 0$ (by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem), so you should not expect to be able to bound local behavior by global information like the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: Oops...I lacked context too much....I originally intended BMO...thank you for your answer and I will post another question...

Comment: I don’t think BMO will work either, since BMO functions can have mild singularities (like $\log x$) and the average will always be of the same order as the singularity, so you’ll have a logarithmic divergence as $|Q|\to 0$.